# zsh/bash completion with ruby gem command tool

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bash-completion, zsh-completion

I created a command line ruby gem and would like to have bash or zsh completion. I created and versionned them, but I have to source them manually.

Is there a common way to execute scripts after the gem install, for example to edit the bashrc or zshrc and add the source command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ruby gems:

After installation your script, that placed in `./bin/` folder should automatically appeared in `/usr/bin/` folder.

`zsh` and `bash` on `OS X` automatically suggest me competition for all commands, that placed in `/usr/bin/` directory.

Possible problems, that can prevent code completions for your gem:

- check, that your gem-file is executable (`chmod +x file`)
- after installation open new terminal window to update shell settings.